# Create UIScrollView within TabViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on an app where I have a TabBarController, and within the first tab, I would like to have a UIScrollView (or something else that allows me to scroll) that will scroll through a few different ViewControllers.

So basically when clicking the first tab it goes to the UIScrollView, which then allows you to scroll through ViewControllers1-3

Click the second tab and go to ViewController 4

Click the third tab and go to ViewController 5

Tab controller seems to be the easy part, but getting the UIScrollView Controller inside of it has not seemed to work AT ALL so far.

Has anyone done anything like this? And would you mind explaining how do it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would be very straightforward to build:

1. Create your 5 view controllers.
2. Create a container view controller with a `UIScrollView` subview.  Add the views from view controller's 1, 2, and 3 to the scroll view, stacking them vertically.  So if view 1 is inserted at `{0,0}`, view 2 will be inserted at `{0, view1.view.frame.size.height}`, and view 3 at `{0, view1.view.frame.size.height + view2.view.frame.size.height}`.
3. Set the `contentSize` of your scroll view to the height of the three view controllers (`viewController1.view.frame.size.height + viewController2.view.frame.size.height + viewController3.view.frame.size.height`).
4. Create your `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs, one for the container view controller with the scroll view (contains view controllers 1-3), one with view controller 4, and one with view controller 5.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using ContainerViewController's on the first tab.  Drag and size the containerviewcontrollers onto the scrollview.  Then delete the ViewController that comes attached with it and create a segue to the viewcontrollers you want to scroll through using embed.